# Вопрос по массивам Java

Tags: java, массивы

В данный момент решаю задачи с codewards. Помогите, пожалуйста, с решением, не понимаю что делаю не так.
Дано 2 массива `int` (Кстати мой наставник, сказал не использовать коллекции в решении, так как нужно сначала научиться работать сложно, а потом переходить на простые решения). Например, в каждом по 8 чисел. Нужно написать программу, которая будет брать число из первого массива, возводить его в квадрат и искать результат во втором массиве и так 8 раз. Если результат возведения найден - вернуть `true`; Нет? - `false`. Я написал 3 вариации решения:

1. Просто сложил все числа второго массива, сложил квадраты чисел первого массива, проверил на равенство и вуаля, все получилось. НО! codewards данное решение не принял, видимо потому что оно не универсальное.
   Выглядит решение так:

```
class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {121, 144, 19, 161, 19, 144, 19, 11};
        int[] b = {121, 14641, 20736, 361, 25921, 361, 20736, 361};

        System.out.println(comp(a,b));
    }

    public static boolean comp(int [] a, int[] b){
        boolean result = false;
        int result1=0;
        int result2=0;
        if(a.length == b.length && a.length!=0){
            for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
                int square = (int) Math.pow(a[i],2);
                result1 = result1+square;
                result2 = result2+b[i];

            }

        }
        else result=false;
        if(result1==result2){
            result = true;
        }else result=false;
        return result;
    }

}
```

Данное решение, как я уже говорил, не прошло.

Вот другое решение. НО! Почему то, при этом решении IDEA, всегда выводит `true`. Пробуя поменять любое число в массиве, все равно выводится `true`, помогите пожалуйста, уважаемые (надеюсь) будущие коллеги!

```
package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {121, 144, 19, 161, 19, 144, 19, 11};
        int[] b = {121, 14641, 20736, 361, 25921, 361, 20736, 361};
        System.out.println(haveAllPows(a, b));
    }

    public static boolean haveAllPows(int[] a, int[] b) {
        boolean result = false;

        if (a.length == b.length && a.length != 0) {
            sort(a);
            sort(b);
            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                int square = (int) Math.pow(a[i],2);
                int other = b[i];
                System.out.println(square);
                System.out.println(other);
                if (other == square){
                    result=true;
                }
                else result=false;
            }
            
            }
        else result = false;
        return result;
    }

    public static int[] sort(int[] a) {
        boolean sorted = false;
        int temp;
        while (!sorted) {
            sorted = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
                if (a[i] > a[i + 1]) {
                    temp = a[i];
                    a[i] = a[i + 1];
                    a[i + 1] = temp;
                    sorted = false;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
        }
        return a;
    }

}
```

Выводы на экран, делал для того, что бы понять, что с чем сравнивает компьютер. И ничего не понятно. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: `Нужно написать программу, которая будет брать число из первого массива, возводить его в квадрат и искать результат во втором массиве и так 8 раз` - если у вас задача поиска, то вам надо испольщовать соотвествующие структуры данных, например, HashSet, иначе вы можете выйти за лимиты времени на задачу.

Comment: также приводите изначальные условия задания, а не свой пересказ. Ваше решение не соотвествует вашей постановке задачи. Например вот такие массиывы [1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 3] по вашей постановке задачи корректные, по вашему решению - нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перебор в сложности. Как впрочем и всегда... Разумеется, здесь коллекция типа сет может все упростить, но раз вы по условию коллекции использовать не хотите, то можно и без них

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {121, 144, 19, 161, 19, 144, 19, 11};
        int[] b = {121, 14641, 20736, 361, 25921, 361, 20736, 361};        
        System.out.println(comp(a, b));
    }

    private static boolean comp(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {        
        return Arrays.stream(arr1).allMatch(value -> contains(arr2, value*value));
    }
    
    private static boolean contains(int[] arr, int numb) {
        return Arrays.stream(arr).anyMatch(value -> value==numb);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Вау, это очень круто. Подскажите пожалуйста, где можно посмотреть документации классов? Я смотрю на oracle, однако не вижу там методов которые вы используете в свое изумительно хорошем решении. Если Вам не трудно, просто скиньте ссылку, а я постараюсь разобраться. Так как я искал документацию, для того, что бы понять какие методы можно использовать при работе с массивами, но мне выползла одна чушь. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html

Comment: @al20ivan Java Stream Api - гугл в помощь. сразу предупреждаю, что стримы появились в версии 8, посему ,если текущая версия ниже, то такой фокус не пройдет...

Comment: Понял, спасибо Вам большое!

Answer (score 0):

В первом случае могут просто "удачно" попасться элементы. Например `a = {3, 4}; b = {5,0}`. Сумма квадратов `a` и сумма `b` совпадут, но нужных квадратов там не будет.

Во втором случае у вас последнее сравнение будет результатом, проигнорировав все остальные.

И задание у вас изложено не совсем понятно, чтобы давать более подробные комментарии:

Нужно чтобы второй массив **содержал** квадраты первого. Т.е. `a = {1,2,1};b = {1,4,9} —> True`.

Или чтобы он **состоял** из них?

Comment: Добрый день! Смотрите: дано 2 массива. В первом содержатся числа. Если мы возьмем число из 1 массива --> возведем его в квадрат --> результат данной математической операции будет представлен во втором массиве --> вернуть true; То есть: Если есть массив: a={2,3,4}, а второй {16,4,9} --> вернуть true. Если есть массив a={2,3,4}, а второй массив {16,3,9} --> вернуть false, так как квадрат первого числа "2", первого массива, не найден во втором массиве.